# Smooth-scrollbar is not working on body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a design where I have used [smooth-scrollbar](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar) for smooth scrolling.

I have implemented it twice on my page, first on the entire page and second on a div element.

It is working fine on the div element but not on the body.

I am unable to scroll as the browser continuously displays the default scrollbar.

Here is my code that I've done so far

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Jain University</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href='../css/aos.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='../css/smooth-scrollbar.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main-scrollbar" data-scrollbar>

    <div class="container-fluid slide slide1" data-color="#EF6C00">
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <img src="../images/homepage1.jpg" class="img-responsive">           
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid slide slide2" data-color="#009688">
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="../images/homepage1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2" data-aos="fade-left">
            <div class="simplebar-content aboutus" data-scrollbar>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu fermentum justo. Sed feugiat nunc in elit sagittis tristique. Duis eget volutpat enim. Aenean bibendum metus sed enim egestas, ultrices mattis enim vulputate. Nullam sem enim, venenatis at leo non, feugiat accumsan mi. Vivamus sagittis purus a volutpat lobortis. Donec vestibulum non elit mollis feugiat. Donec ultricies viverra suscipit. Quisque maximus lacus nec tortor varius, eu accumsan massa blandit. Pellentesque auctor ligula sit amet urna ornare, et cursus est interdum. Cras scelerisque, lectus nec semper ultrices, diam tellus posuere sapien, eget maximus lectus magna non elit. Mauris convallis justo enim, at malesuada quam imperdiet vitae. Ut urna dui, sagittis a dolor eu, eleifend elementum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/aos.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script> Scrollbar.initAll(); </script>
        <script>
            AOS.init({
                easing: 'ease-out-back',
                duration: 1000
            });

        </script>
<script>
    $(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(".slide1").position().top) {
            $('body').css('background', $(".slide1").attr("data-color"));
            $('.navbar').css({'background': $(".slide1").attr("data-color"),opacity:'0.9'});

        };
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > $(".slide2").position().top) {
            $('body').css('background', $(".slide2").attr("data-color"));
            $('.navbar').css({'background': $(".slide2").attr("data-color"),opacity:'0.9'});
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anybody here to help??

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a height to each item otherwise it will not work

```
[data-scrollbar]{
  height: 500px;/*<<<<<required*/
}
```

yay JS

```
<script>
  Scrollbar.initAll({
    alwaysShowTracks: true,
    overscrollEffect: "bounce"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: well it's working fine for div but for body it's not working I want to change default browser scrollbar but it's only working on div not on browser..

Comment: add `<body  data-scrollbar>`

Comment: scrollbar is disappeared and also it's not scrolling now

Comment: Everything depends on the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) of each element. Usually the body is 100%